# Correctly format Windows date in R

Tags: r, date

In R, I'm working with a dataframe that has been imported from Excel. This dataframe contains dates, such as the following:

```
#in Excel    
01/01/1980, 01/01/2006, 01/03/2023, 01/07/2010, 01/04/2006, 01/08/2013
```

These dates are imported as numbers, unfortunately also in the character format (probably because there are `NA` values):

```
> dates
 [1] "29221" "38718" "44986" "40360" "38808" "41487" "40544" "30682" "NA"    "NA"    "37987" "36526" "41640"
[14] "40909" "44896" "38718" "37622" "35796" "41275" "43466" "43101" "40909" "37257" "39814" "44562" "37987"
[27] "37987" "40179" "35431" "39448" "40909" "43101" "40915" "38718" "35065" "41640" "40909" "36161" "42491"
[40] "38718" "39825" "40909"

> str(dates)
 chr [1:42] "29221" "38718" "44986" "40360" "38808" "41487" "40544" "30682" "NA" "NA" "37987" "36526" ...
```

Now, I want to convert them to correctly formatted dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format. If I use `as.Date`, they are converted to incorrect dates in the future, which must be due to the discrepancy between the Windows and Unix date formats. For example, `29221` is converted to `2050-01-02`, rather than to `1980-01-01`.

How do I resolve this?

To create the dates:

```
dates <- c("29221", "38718", "44986", "40360", "38808", "41487", "40544", "30682", "NA", "NA", "37987", "36526", "41640", "40909", "44896", "38718", "37622", "35796", "41275", "43466", "43101", "40909", "37257", "39814", "44562", "37987", "37987", "40179", "35431", "39448", "40909", "43101", "40915", "38718", "35065", "41640", "40909", "36161", "42491", "38718", "39825", "40909")
```

Edit: added some more examples

Comment: Which format are the dates in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need specify the `origin` date, for example

```
> d <- c("29221", "38718", "44986", "40360", "38808")

> as.Date(as.numeric(d), origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "1980-01-01" "2006-01-01" "2023-03-01" "2010-07-01" "2006-04-01"
```

Comment: If the data comes directly from Excel `origin = 1899-12-30` should give correct results.

Comment: @s_baldur yes, you are right. now I updated my solution with that origin date